# manual for mysql connector/C++

Tags: c++, mysql, database, mysql-workbench

I have come across several documents on using mysql connector/C++ with all of them using different functions for the same things.
e.g

```
`sql::mysql::MySQL_Driver *driver;
sql::Connection *con;
driver = sql::mysql::MySQL_Driver::get_mysql_driver_instance(); 
con = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "user", "password");`
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/en/connector-cpp-examples-complete-example-1.html

and another

```
MYSQL* conn;
conn = mysql_init(NULL);
mysql_real_connect(conn,HOST,USERNAME,PASSWORD,DATABASE,0,NULL,0);
```

http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/6370/

In the first one, i cant find the header files used.
I have "mysql community 5.6".
I cant find "mysql.h" in "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\include\mysql.h" which allows me to be able to use the second method.

The problem is ive not found any manual or reference that explains the functions.

Can any one help me?

Comment: I had the same issue today. Asking around, my colleague suggested that google and stackoverflow seem to be the best places to look for answers.

Answer (score 0):

You should differenciate between the 2 connection methods. The first one is using the MySQL C++ connector, while the second one uses the C connector (aka. MySQL client lib). The C++ connector is not installed by default

Using the very comfortable [MySQL Windows Installer](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/installer/) will let you select the dev parts for MySQL so that you get all headers etc. (for the C connector) and/or other connectors (like C++, ODBC etc.) for other access methods.

But obviously, you should decide for one way to manage connections and stay with that. Mixing connectors is not a good idea, as they are maintaining internal states which are not communicated between the involved connectors.

If you ask me for a recommendation I'd say use the C++ connector if you can, as it has additional handling for connection + result set management.